# How can I move existing data to new row?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with several thousand rows.  I'd like to be able to take one of those rows and duplicate it into a new row.  What is the best way to do this?

Should I grab the rows data and assign each field into a variable?  And then take those variables and insert them into a new row?

So that'd be two queries -- is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO tablename SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE <your where condition>
```

If a primary key is in the way

```
INSERT INTO tablename (every, field, except, primary) SELECT every, field, except, primary FROM tablename WHERE <your where condition>
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO tablename SELECT NULL, every, field, except, primary FROM tablename WHERE <your where condition>
```

(assuming the id is the first column)

Explicitly naming the columns you're going the use (the 2nd query in this answer) should be preferred for production code.

Comment: I think that, too, is where the problem is.  First field is ID which is primary and unique.

Comment: Indeed, but as the OP said 'duplicate' I assumed a complete duplicate. Now, in what real world example we would *need* an exact duplicate is entirely open for debate. (edit answer with solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Check out mysql's [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) syntax.

You should be able to do something like:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (a, b, c) SELECT a, b, c FROM tbl WHERE id = 1234;
```